# How to change key binding for Tmux

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, tmux

I want to change the key binding in Tmux so I can use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>

instead of

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

This is my (unfortunately) not working try to do so.

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix M-C
```

What's wrong with this? I thought I followed the documentation for the keys.

Comment: Note: the config files do not come by default, you need to create /etc/tmux.conf for global config. If you have the global config then tmux will also look for personal config file at ~/.tmux.conf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do indeed have the correct syntax for changing the command prefix in tmux. But unfortunately you cannot use the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> as a command prefix. Both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> are only used in combination with other keys, but never alone and never with each other. For example,

- `C-b` stands for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- `M-n` stands for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Your attempt to bind `M-C` actually means <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (meta prefix with uppercase C). Similarly, `C-M` would mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

In short, you have to combine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with some other key or <kbd>Alt</kbd> with some other key, not with each other.

Comment: A link to the reference would be helpful.